# React doesn't re-render components after state changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a todo app and I have some problem

I got a feature to add a todo item to favorite and so objects with "favorite: true" should be first at the array of all todos.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Sort array of objects with favorite true were first
    setTodos(todos.sort((x, y) => Number(y.favorite) - Number(x.favorite)));
  }, [todos]);

//Add to favorite function
  const favoriteHandler = () => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((e) => {
        if (e.id === id) {
          return {
            ...e,
            favorite: e.favorite,
          };
        }
        return e;
      })
    );
  };

<div className="favorite-button" onClick={() => favoriteHandler()}>
          {favorite ? (
            <img src={FavoriteFilledIcon} alt="Remove from favorite" />
          ) : (
            <img src={FavoriteIcon} alt="Add to favorite" />
          )}
        </div>
```

but if click on a favoriteHandler console log tells me that objects with favorite: true is at the start of array, but todos.map doesn't re-render this changes, why?

```
// App.js
{todos.map((e, i) => (
          <TodoItem
            completed={e.completed}
            id={e.id}
            key={i}
            text={e.name}
            setTodos={setTodos}
            todos={todos}
            favorite={e.favorite}
          />
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no re-render because no state is being change.

In favoriteHandler function you are just setting the favorite as the initial favorite you supplied as props. If you're trying to toggle favorite on click you should consider using boolean operator as below.

```js
  const favoriteHandler = () => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((e) => {
        if (e.id === id) {
          return {
            ...e,
            favorite: !e.favorite,
          };
        }
        return e;
      })
    );
  };
```

In terms of sorting you won't need to use useEffect hook but re-write as following:

```js
  todos
    .sort((x, y) => Number(y.favorite) - Number(x.favorite))
    .map((todo) => {
      return (
        <TodoItem
          completed={todo.completed}
          id={todo.id}
          key={todo.id}
          text={todo.text}
          setTodos={setTodos}
          todos={todos}
          favorite={todo.favorite}
        />
      );
    });
```

For Improvement in your code I suggest the following.

1. Try to use a more straightforward variable name like `todo` and stay away from variables name like `e`.
2. Instead of attaching `onClick` on div tag, use button tags.
3. When you are trying to map over an array and have a unique key, you should use that key instead of index.

Comment: thank you a lot, i tried to add sort function but after mapping all todos my silly brain